# Is there a way to upload secure files to azure devops library automatically?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to upload keys to azure devops as secure files to use in pipeline context, I only found manual upload but it is not option, Is there a way it can be automated thorough powershell or any pipeline tasks? please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use REST API to do this:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=5.0-preview.1&name={fileName}

Content-Type=application/octet-stream
```

Please check [this topic](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9172) on GitHUb.

You will find [there](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9172#issuecomment-626474029) even powershell script:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $PAT,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$AzureDevOpsOrg,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$AzureDevOpsProjectID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SecureNameFile2Upload,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SecureNameFilePath2Upload
)

try{
    $base64AuthInfo=[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$PAT)))
    $uploadSecureFileURI="https://dev.azure.com/$AzureDevOpsOrg/$AzureDevOpsProjectID/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=5.0-preview.1&name=$SecureNameFile2Upload"
    $headers = @{
        Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadSecureFileURI -Method Post -ContentType "application/octet-stream" -Headers $headers -InFile "$SecureNameFilePath2Upload"
}
catch
{
    write-host -f Red "Error upload client certificate file [$SecureNameFilePath2Upload] to AzureDevOps secure file!" $_.Exception.Message
    throw "Error occors -> $_.Exception.Message"
}
```

Comment: @BalaMurali cool. Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Comment: of course. It really helped , at least i didn't find on microsoft docs.

Comment: do you know the AD scope of this API? I am trying to do it with az rest but I need to provide the scope. I cannot figure out what the scope is.

Comment: @BalaMurali, it is still missing regards to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/623)

Comment: @ikhvjs docs is still missing under distributed tasks

Answer (score 0):

From [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9172#issuecomment-655569961)

I copied here for future reference.

> NOTE: The build service must have the role of Creator for secure files
> to be able to upload them from a pipeline.
> Blockquote

NO document yet as of today(Mar 2024) regards to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/623)

```yaml
### The variables secureFileFolder & secureFileName references variables I have defined higher up in the pipeline.
- task: PowerShell@2
  enabled: true
  displayName: "Upload Secure File"
  inputs:
      targetType: "inline"
      script: |
          $header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:ACCESSTOKEN" }
          $infile = "$(secureFileFolder)/$(secureFileName)"
          $organization = (Split-Path $(System.CollectionUri) -leaf)
          $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=5.0-preview.1&name=$(secureFileName)"

          Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/octet-stream" -Headers $header -InFile "$infile"
  env:
      ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```